# "cannot convert from 'UnityEngine.Vector3' to 'UnityEngine.Space" trying to rotate camera with joystick

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, vector, camera, rotation

so i want to rotate the camera horizontally with joystick but it is giving me an error.

cannot convert from 'UnityEngine.Vector3' to 'UnityEngine.Space'

```
transform.Rotate(Vector3.up, direction * rotationSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
```

if i remove Vector3.up from the code above the error goes away and i can move the camera with joystick but its rotating vertically. Any way to fix this?

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class RotateCamera : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float rotationSpeed = 50.0f;
    public VariableJoystick variableJoystick;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        //float horizontalInput = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
        //transform.Rotate(Vector3.up, horizontalInput * rotationSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
       Vector3 direction = Vector3.forward * variableJoystick.Vertical + Vector3.right * variableJoystick.Horizontal;
        transform.Rotate(Vector3.up, direction * rotationSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
    }

}
```

Comment: Rotate takes two arguments: A Vector3 expression the desired rotation in Euler angles per axis, and a second argument expressing whether or not you wish to rotate in local (self) or world space. So you'll need to combine your current arguments into a single Vector3 and pass that instead. See https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.Rotate.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you want

```
transform.Rotate(Vector3.up * variableJoystick.Horizontal * rotationSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
```

then, or also maybe easier to read

```
transform.Rotate(0, variableJoystick.Horizontal * rotationSpeed * Time.deltaTime, 0);
```

Comment: so replacing 'direction' with 'variableJoystick.Horizontal' did the wonder i guess? you saved me bro thanks.

Comment: No not only replacing.. note that instead of a `,` there is a `*` .. you use the `up` vector as direction and the joystick + additional modifiers as a factor